# How to write an entry (valueName and value) in Windows Registry

Tags: java, windows, registry

Similar question was already ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) and there're a lot of good answers. I choosed the piece of code from the 1. answer and with given good example could read some value from Windows Registry (WR). 
Can anyone give me a good example please to write an entry (valueName and Value) in WR? I'm not familiar with Java and that's why it's a little complicated for me to understand it without example:( 
The main Key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, Subkey is `Software\\Wow6432Node\\mySoft`. The valueName and value that I want to write are: `myPwd` and `a`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer back to the same link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) first answer to use the provided class WinRegistry, and then you can use its function `writeStringValue`

For example, in your case:

```
WinRegistry.writeStringValue( WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Wow6432Node\\mySoft", "myPwd", "a" );
```

Comment: I've already used this function, but the entry didn't appear in my WR. I thought I could be because of my redused rights on the computer, but there was also no `Exception` like `IllegalAccessException`. The function is just being called but nothing more appears. Do you know what could be the reason for it?

Comment: you can debug this line `Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();` to see if you can get it fine with permission. Alternatively, which JVM u use? if 64bit, please try to copy 64bit version of WinRegistry provided from other answers of the same link